# Attachment - Gmail to Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Script to get the attachment of a determined e-mail.

```
function PegarEmail123() {

try{

var a = GmailApp.search("Acompanhamento Retorno AMB - Grupo EAB");
var b = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(a);
var c = b[0][0].getAttachments()[0].copyBlob();
var d = DriveApp.getFolderById("1osXj_L0WmVFYWdi1LJgsD5fo436pokj_").createFile(c)
var hoje = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Sao_Paulo", "dd/MM/yyyy");
GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), '3191 TOG', 'O arquivo utilizado para atualizar o 3191 do dia '+hoje+' foi o '+d.getName());
```

It works fine with a lot of Sheets, but on this one, somehow it gets only the e-mail that was sent on 08/14/2022, as you can see the file save on Drive:

[File saved on Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Btul.jpg)

And the e-mail that I received today:

[e-mail received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEadm.jpg)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question doesn't include enough details and the script is incomplete ( at least `catch` is missing). Are you the only user of this script? How the script is executed? Have signed in only on one Google account or on multiple accounts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is the entire Script.
It's only to get the attachment and save on drive. It works fine with a lot of sheets and other subjects.
I'm not the only user, but the problem happens with everyone.
The script is executed by trigger, but as it doesn't work, i'm running it manually.

This is the line that gets the attachment:
var c = b[0][0].getAttachments()[0].copyBlob();

And this is the line that creates a file with it:
var d = DriveApp.getFolderById("1osXj_L0WmVFYWdi1LJgsD5fo436pokj_").createFile(c)